# how to convert text file to adjancency matrix in python

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have text file which includes:

1 2
1 5
2 3
2 5
3 4

I am new in python, How can I convert those data from .txt into adjacency matrix in python? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your input to the question instead of providing a link.You also need to provide the expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - convert edge list to adjacency matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151734/python-convert-edge-list-to-adjacency-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the code

that will read from input file and builds adjacency matrix

```
f = open("graph.txt", 'r')
graph = {}
n = 0
for i in f.readlines():
    nodes = i.split(" ")
    n1 = int(nodes[0])
    n2 = int(nodes[1])
    if n < n1 and n1 > n2:
        n = n1
    if n < n2 and n2 > n1:
        n = n2
    if n1 not in list(graph):
        graph[n1] = []
    adjacencyList = graph[n1]
    adjacencyList.append(n2)
    graph[n1] = adjacencyList

adjacencyMatrix = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    row = []
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        if i in list(graph) and j in graph[i]:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(0)
    adjacencyMatrix.append(row)

for i in range(n):
    row = ""
    for j in range(n):
        row += str(adjacencyMatrix[i][j])+" "

    print(row)
```

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: this doesn't build an adjacency matrix. You're creating a dictionary with the first value as key, and second value as value.

Comment: The second line would replace the value of graph[1] to 5

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Let me know the status

Comment: You are creating a dict which shows connected nodes at each node. This is not an adjacency matrix. This is what an adjacency matrix looks [like](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/a773011024de5e3cbe8da03e97c79e1fe3101937)

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Done!!

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Is it Okay now?

Comment: @TilakPutta ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'

Comment: @Ashish make sure your file does not have any extra lines

Comment: yep, this works. But solution is overkill. Also, you just gave him his assignment solution

Comment: @Usernamenotfound LOL! nothing worked for me till now! thanks though.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're attempting to solve some graph problem. Read all the lines and create a square matrix with rows=columns=max number in the list

Then depending on whether the graph is directional or not you should fill in the locations in the matrix with a 1.

For example

```
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
```

where n is the maximum number of nodes in the graph.

Then your first line should be assigned to

```
Matrix[0][1] = 1 
Matrix[1][0] = 1 //this line if graph is not directional
```

Comment: can you please give an example in coding?

Comment: I'm not going to provide the complete solution to your homework. The example above gives you the exact code to create an adjacency list. If you plug this into @TilakPutta's code above instead of the dict you should get the answer